# How can I do like this style in writing?

Tags: fonts, titles, text

I want to write as this font in text and equation and do the same style of this image like alignment and do the line up of page..., any one know that

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the `titlesec` package.

Comment: no i hav'nt......................

Comment: It was a suggestion :)

Comment: ohh ,ok ..............

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... can you provide a `MWE` or please post the code what you tried to achieve this?